# How can I call constants in db file?

Tags: php, mysql

this is my db file

```
config.php

define(HOST_NAME, "localhost");
define(USER, "root");
define(PASSWORD, "");
define(DATABASE, "xxx");
```

now i wanted to call these constants in my db file

```
db.php
class Database {
function db_connect() {
$conn =mysql_connect(HOST_NAME, USER, PASSWORD);
}
}
$obj_db = new Database();
$obj_db->db_connect();
```

but these constants are not coming in mysql_connect and its giving error

```
 Unknown MySQL server host 'HOST_NAME' (11001)
```

please help
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should have `config.php` been included by `include 'config.php';`.

There are 4 ways of doing this:

```
include 'config.php';
include_once 'config.php';
require 'config.php';
require_once 'config.php';
```

PS: You need the quotes when define the constant.

```
define('HOST_NAME', "localhost");
define('USER', "root");
define('PASSWORD', "");
define('DATABASE', "xxx");
```

Comment: file is already included but the variables are not assigning in `mysql_connect();`

Comment: @Sparkx Your define need quotes.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
include 'config.php';
```

or

```
require 'config.php';
```

?

Comment: file is already included but the variables are not assigning in `mysql_connect();`